# How to use Jmeter Xpath extractor for multiple run in dynamic API elements

Tags: java, jmeter, xpath, jmeter-plugins

XPath extractor response assertion passed **first run** but in **second run** it is getting failed because `<name>pc</name>` is not coming in API. How to skip this element if it is not coming in **second run** without failing response assertion or any suggestions for this?

***API response first run:***

[image]

***API response in second run***: missing element < name > pc < /name >

[image]

[image]

**Response assertion** - DB values(name_1)using jdbc request match with xml element(name) in API response

[image]

Comment: How are first and 2nd (following) samplers defined? Is it the same thread for instance? Or just the 2nd and subsequent call or...?

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

- **either** you add an [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) checking the content of the name in the response (clause be like `${__groovy( ${name}?.trim() )}` ) and put inside there the assertion, so to avoid asserting if the name is empti
- **or** you try to make it pass even if the name is empty: you need to figure out why the API is returning an empty name; in that case your comparing value (***expected value***) should be empty as well; you cannot have the test pass if an expected information is not returned

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use ***/part01[position()<2]*** as a value of XPath query. I think it will solve your problem.

[image: XPath Extractor]

Answer (score 0):

use `JSR223 Assertion` for assertion. So, you'll have better control over it.

```
String responseData = vars.get("name");
```